# How do I get a BCM4313 with airodump-ng working in monitor mode?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, aircrack-ng

I noticed that the STA driver can't work in monitor mode so I disabled it. I am now using brcmsmac dirver.

Here is the output from lshw for this wireless card:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 70:f1:a1:71:b2:6f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.2.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.5.185 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:fbd00000-fbd03fff
```

I stop the network-manager and avahi-daemon and try to start it in monitor mode and mon0 is created.

The problem is that airodump-ng never catches anything on all channels. Do I need a new card to work in monitor mode ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same card and works great. I dont know where u live but u should get some air traffic. The problem with this broadcom wifi is that it is not a powerful. So try it outside, go to other places and try to get some :)

disconnect from wifi

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

`sudo macchanger -r wlan0` if u have macchanger

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
sudo airodump-ng mon0
```

Comment: It doesn't get any traffic even from wireless access points 2 meters away

Comment: is your wireless up?

Comment: I do ifdown on the interface then "airmon-ng start wlan0" to start monitoring. Can you please tell me which driver are you using ?

Comment: the same brcmsmac. Why ifdown??

Comment: try it like this:
`disconnect from wifi`  
`sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`
`sudo macchanger -r wlan0 ` if u have macchanger
`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`
`sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`
`sudo airodump-ng mon0`

Comment: Thanks. I edited your answer to mark the question as answered.

Comment: np man :) as long it is working